# Check if a NSView is visible in its NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, appkit

How can I know if my `NSView` is visible within its `NSWindow`?

It needs to account for scrolling superviews.

It does **not** need to know if the `NSWindow` is visible to the user.

Accounting for overlapping views would be "nice to have" but not required.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
@interface NSView (Visibility)
- (BOOL)visibleInWindow;
@end

@implementation NSView (Visibility)

- (BOOL)visibleInWindow
{
  if (self.window == nil) {
    return NO;
  }

  // Might have zero opacity.
  if (self.alphaValue == 0 || self.hiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor) {
    return NO;
  }

  // Might be clipped by an ancestor.
  return !NSIsEmptyRect(self.visibleRect);
}

@end
```

**Note:** Overlapping views are not accounted for.

Comment: +1 but intersecting with the window bounds shouldn't be necessary. The `contentView` is an ancestor, so it's already checked by `visibleRect`.

Comment: @KenThomases True!