# Check if View is visible on screen in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsview, nswindow

How can I know if my `SwiftUI` `View` is visible on screen on macOS?

I found [an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834445/3917662) that uses a `NSView` extension:

```
public extension NSView {
    var isVisible: Bool {
        
        if self.window == nil {
            return false
        }
        
        if self.alphaValue == 0.0 {
            return false
        }
        
        if self.isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor {
            return false
        }
        
        return !NSIsEmptyRect(self.visibleRect)
        
    }
}
```

... but I have no idea how to observe changes.

I’m aware of `NSWindow.didChangeOcclusionStateNotification` but I do need to know if my `View` is visible, not its `NSWindow`.

Comment: Did you tried with onAppear and onDisappear ❓

Comment: @PtitXav `.onDisappear` only triggers when the View gets destructed, it does not get called when the View is obscured by another View/Window.

Comment: From what I experienced it is also called when view  a view is pushed on it in a navigation stack.

Comment: @PtitXav I’m on macOS basically searching for a way to detect if my View got obscured by another app window. No NavigationStack used at all in this scenario.